# File not found error in java microservice

Tags: java, spring, file, microservices

I have 2 microservices

From service A the file is generated by making operations on the file

From service B the file is getting used

the sequence is

step 1: access the API of service B /getFile

step 2: while processing the API of service B it does the API calls to generate file in service A

step 3: when the file is generated we check if the file is available on the file system (which is the shared file system of services A and B)

step 4: once the response is successfully received from service A service B continues the processing

in above scenario if we use file.exists() in service A it returns true
but if we use it in service B it returns a false

also checked that the file is getting checked after the response of service A is received.

Can anyone help me why this kind of behavior is being replicated?

To check file exist please find the below code

in service B

```
File file = Paths.get(uri).toFile();
log.debug("isFile():" + file.isFile() + " exists():" + file.exists())
```

in service A

```
File file = new File(uri);
log.debug("isFile():" + file.isFile() + " exists():" + file.exists())
```

Comment: Don't use `Paths.get().toFile()`. Instead use `Files.exists` and `Files.isRegularFile` with the `Path`.

Comment: Login on the system using SSH and take a look. Does the file not exists at all or it appears with a delay? What happens, if you tries to open the file by name without checking if it exists?

Comment: Seems like that the routes to find the file is a relative file so works on serviceA but serviceB not. 

Suggest to sysout this code on boot to trace where serviceA or serviceB are located:

    Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString()

Comment: Where are the services hosted? What does the URL look like in each service? Are you certain the two services share the same file system?

Comment: @30thh The generated file exists in the shared file system and it is accessible after some delay (within ms I think) as we check the availability from service A (from where the file is getting generated) it returns as available on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a limitation of you shared filesystem. Depending on the solution it can takes time the change is propagated to all the nodes and all the clients.

Try to read the file by name without checking if the file exists.

For example NFS client has a cache for file and directory attributes. See this topic about NFS:

[howto force refresh NFS cache when checking newly created file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026752/howto-force-refresh-nfs-cache-when-checking-newly-created-file)

---

If you are mounting an AWS S3 bucket or similar cloud storage it could be even more sophisticated. Such a storage is usually eventually consistent without a guarantied possibility to get the last version of the file in a general case. Take a look into the manual for the suggested solutions.